# Computer audio solution with sidetone

Tags: audio-adapters

I'm looking for an audio board or USB dongle that has proper [sidetone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidetone).

I don't use a headset with integrated mic because I don't like the bad sound quality. Instead I have a separate desk microphone plugged in to the mic port, and earphones. However on my mobo with Windows 10 clicking on the "listen to this device" in the audio settings gives me the microphone audio with a delay of a couple of tenths of a second or so (presumably its made the round trip through the A-D, digital mixing and then D-A). This makes it unusable: if you try talking while listening to your delayed voice it makes you stammer.

So I'm looking for a reasonably cheap, reasonably good quality audio board (either a PCI-E board or USB) that has a proper sidetone setting so that I can hear myself in real time without that delay.

Does anyone have any recommendations? I've looked through Amazon, but most vendors don't even mention it. When they do its not clear whether there is a delay. Nobody uses the word "sidetone".

Comment: If the soft you use allows to playback your mic (without activating the windows option) then you can install the audio driver "ASIO4ALL". This driver allows to reduce to almost nothing latency (I often use it to record some instruments with Adobe Audition). By the way, my headset+mic has a builtin sidetone which is quite useful. Another solution might be to left the "listen to this device" unchecked and go to your headset audio output properties and depending on your machine, you might find a mic level that you can set. Not an answer but looking for a software solution before buying anything.